# WHERE LIKE в  Doctrine 1.4

Tags: php, doctrine

Функция выборки из БД MySQL не дает никакого результата если $query = "bee"?!

```
public function searchCompany($query){
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('VlCompany a')
            ->where('a.product LIKE ?', '%$query%')
            ->execute();
    return $q;
}
```

Но если подставить в запрос 'bee' напрямую, то результат есть!!

```
public function searchCompany($query){
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('VlCompany a')
            ->where('a.product LIKE ?', '%bee%')
            ->execute();
    return $q;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Переменные в одинарных кавычках не подставляются. Оно у вас в базе реально ищет продукт похожий на **`%$query%`**.

- используйте двойные кавычки:     `"%$query%"`
- используйте конкатенацию:    `'%'.$query.'%'`

Comment: как в таком случае обозначить переменную???

Comment: все понял правильный синтаксис "%$query%"